# ASP AutoPostBack is called twice after checkbox is moved using appendTo

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a checkbox with `AutoPostBack` set to true:

```
<div id="section">
    <dx:ASPxCheckBox runat="server" ID="chbxEnabled" Text="Enable something" AutoPostBack="True" ClientInstanceName="chbxEnabled"  />
</div>
```

The checkbox is inside HTML code which is moved by jQuery `appendTo` command:

```
$('#section').appendTo('#anotherSection');
```

What happens is that after the `appendTo` command the checkbox post back is called twice.
I can see in Chrome Debugger that there are 2 `click` event listeners on the checkbox.

Without moving the section there is only one event registered.

How can I fix it?